# Adding datagridtemplate column and data during runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a datagrid with a column defined at design time.

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Opacity="50" Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntToImageConverter}}" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

But in  my application the number of columns and rows will be decided during runtime based on a data table.
How can I create this template column (by calling the above template) and how can I add rows to that (number of columns will be around 600-1000)?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to bind Columns property to a list of columns and use a ValueConverter for putting your logic for choosing a proper DataTemplate which you have already defined in resources for different types of data rows.